# Filter web socket messages into multiple Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my angular application, I am using web sockets to receive asynchronous  messages from my back-end. So I have created an angular service to handle this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as SocketIO from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EventService {
    private socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = SocketIO();
    }

    onMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
            this.socket.on('message', (message: string) => {
                observer.next(JSON.parse(message))
            });
        });
    }
}
```

My messages have different types and are JSON formatted this way:

```js
{
    "type": "HELLO",
    "data": "hello world !"
}
```

Currently, I use the `EventService.onMessage().subscribe(...)` function to handle messages in the only component which need them.

---

Now, I need to have multiple message types. Which will be used by multiple components.

I would like to create a method which return an Observable by message types. Something like that:

```js
export class EventService {
    ...

    onHello(): Observable<any> { ... }

    onFoo(): Observable<any> { ... }

    onBar(): Observable<any> { ... }
}
```

Is it possible ? How to do it ? Is the back-end architecture correct (maybe I should split into multiple web sockets) ?

Comment: I may not have been able to make my title relevant. Feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fact, as I am using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) there a simple solution.

I was sending data in my back-end using the [`send()`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-send-%E2%80%A6args-ack) function:

```js
const io = require('socket.io');
const ws = io(...);

ws.on('connection', function(socket) {
    ...

    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: "HELLO",
        data: "hello world !"
    }));
});
```

Which send a `'message'` which can be receive using [`on('message', ...)`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback).

But I should use the [`emit()`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack) function instead which allow to set the event name:

```js
const io = require('socket.io');
const ws = io(...);

ws.on('connection', function(socket) {
    ...

    socket.emit('hello', JSON.stringify({
        data: "hello world !"
    }));
});
```

So now my angular service could be:

```js
export class EventService {
   ...

    onHello(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>(observer => {
            this.socket.on('hello', (message: string) => {
                observer.next(JSON.parse(message))
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try in different way:
create subjects for each message type, and in onMessage method apply message to specyfic subject

```
onHello() = new Subject()/new BehaviorSubject(initialValue)
...

onMessage() {
  this.socket.on('message', message => {
    let msg = JSON.parse(message);
    if(msg.type === 'hello'){
      this.onHello.next(msg);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have found an easier solution, but thanks for pointing me out the [`RxJS Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject).